# Turning an autocomplete selection into a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm using this function to do Google Places Autocomplete Search

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function initialize() {
     var input = (document.getElementById('pac-input'));
     var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input));
  }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
})
```

I want to turn the selected location into a cookie so I can then go on and use it in a rails method.

How would I take the end selection and turn it into a cookie?

[image]

Comment: The answer would depend of exactly what you want to do. Maybe you need to take a look to this first and edit your question if needed http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Use [Jquery-cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) OR [Js-cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

Comment: I want to extract the string of the location selected so I can use it in a rails method.

Comment: I don't think it is entirely clear why you need cookies.  Why don't you just send the input value via ajax?  Why do you need to store state information on the client?

Comment: It's actually not on the client, I want to store information on the place. The client is going to review the location. I want to store only those locations that have been reviewed, as opposed to every location in the world.